# Segment LCD only viewable at extreme angles

Tags: lcd, repair

I have a kitchen scale with a segment LCD display. Starting one day, the LCD display is barely legible at all; sometimes the numbers are viewable from an extreme angle, sometimes not at all. Sometimes it helps if I gently press on the glass.

I have very little experience with LCDs. I've cleaned the contacts to the PCB, which made no difference (I didn't seriously expect it to, since the segments look just fine when visible, it's just that they're hard to see).

Any way to fix the LCD? I rather fix this than throw it out and buy a new kitchen scale.

Comment: Have you tried a new battery?

Comment: Yes, the batteries are fine. Tested them with a voltmeter, and they're pretty close to their nominal voltage. Tried many sets of batteries, too.

Comment: It could be a loose contact issue on the contrast input to the LCD.

Comment: @ASWINVENU That sounds promising, I'll look into that. To complicate matters, the LCD doesn't have pins, but a continuous strip that sits on top of the contacts on the PCB. No idea what that kind of connection is called.

Comment: It's called a Zebra Strip, at least that's the brand name of one of the versions. It's alternately conductive and insulating elastomer, so gives you continuity between the pins that line up with the board pads, regardless of shifts in the strip.

Comment: Could you fix the problem? I have a simillar issue with a consummption meter...

Comment: All you can really do is try to clean all the contacts and any residue on the circuit board. I've gone through about 3 kitchen scales in about five years and I have never been able to repair any of them.